# Where should I put the catchError operator for higher-order observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

To make api calls in order I'm using the concatMap operator and it works great.

Now I need to **handle the errors on the outer and inner observables individually**.

This is what I've come up with so far

```
 this.cards$
  .pipe(
    concatMap((cards: any[]) => {
      console.table(cards);
      const defaultCard = cards[1];
      return defaultCard.showCaptcha ? this.captcha$ : EMPTY;
    })
  )
  .subscribe((captchaValue: string) => {
    console.log(captchaValue);
  });
```

These are the definition for the cards$ and captcha$ observables:

```
cards = [
    {
      name: 'classic',
      showCaptcha: false,
    },
    {
      name: 'credit',
      showCaptcha: true,
    },
  ];

  cards$ = of(this.cards);
  captcha$ = of('abcd123').pipe(delay(1000));
```

As you can see I only invoke the captcha "service" if the default card has its show property set to true.

I also created the error versions for both the cards$ and captcha$ observables and there is where I ended up putting the catchError operators.

```
cardsWithError$ = throwError(() => Error('Oh no! An error in cards')).pipe(
    delay(1000),
    catchError((error) => {
      console.error('Error inside cards observable', error);
      return EMPTY;
    })
  );

  captchaWithError$ = throwError(() =>
    Error('Oh no! An error in captcha')
  ).pipe(
    delay(1000),
    catchError((error) => {
      console.error('Error inside captcha observable', error);
      return EMPTY;
    })
  );
```

I simulate the errors on the observables by swapping the normal ones but their error versions.

[image]

Now, this seems to work, but since I'm not very familiar with rxjs, I'm not sure this is the right way to implement the error handling for the use case I describe in the beginning of my question.

Here you can find the [complete example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-goxa3q?file=src/main.ts)

Thanks